# JavaFX fill tableView with treeMap data

Tags: javafx, tableview, treemap

I have a `TableView` with two columns, a `TreeMap<String, String>` and an `ObservableMap`. I want to fill the `TableView` with my `TreeMap` data. 
But `tableview.setItems(observableMap)` does not work because `setItems` expects an `ObservableList`. I tried the same with `observableHashMap` which also didn't work. What can I do to fill my `TableView` with my data in the `TreeMap`?

Comment: You need a `ObservableList` not a `ObservableMap`. Just use something like `FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.keySet())` or something like this (it's unclear which part of the `Map` should be used as items for the `TableView`). If you need to adjust the list's contents dynamically based on the content of `observableMap`, it gets more complicated...

Comment: So that means with FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.keySet()) I could only fill my tableView with the keys inside my treeMap? What about the values?

Comment: You want to display the key in one column and the associated value in the other one, I guess? What about updates to the map? Can the map be modified after inserting the data in the `TableView` or is this not a case that needs to be considered? (Adding/removing keys being the most important part to consider in this case.)

Comment: No the data can't be modified in the TableView. And yes one column is for keys and the other one is for the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the keys as item type for the `TableView` and use the `cellValueFactory` for the value column to extract the value:

```
Map<String, String> map = ...

TableView<String> tableView = new TableView();

// fill table with keys
tableView.getItems().addAll(map.keySet());

TableColumn<String, String> keyColumn = new TableColumn<>("key");
keyColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue()));

TableColumn<String, String> valueColumn = new TableColumn<>("value");
valueColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(map.get(cd.getValue())));

tableView.getColumns().addAll(keyColumn, valueColumn);
```

Alternatively you could also use a `TableView<Map.Entry<String, String>>`

```
...

// fill table with keys
tableView.getItems().addAll(map.entrySet());

TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> keyColumn = new TableColumn<>("key");
keyColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("key"));

TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> valueColumn = new TableColumn<>("value");
valueColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value"));

...
```

Comment: I tried your code and the two columns: keyColumn and valueColumn get created on the tableView but unfortunately the content remains empty.

Comment: @UmutFriusSavas Just make sure you are calling `tableView.getItems().addAll(map.keySet())` *after* the map is populated. If it's still not working, you probably have errors elsewhere that are unrelated.

Comment: This results in the table not observing changes in the underlying map model - pretty well defeating the point of TableView using an observable source.